# How must I do when fileter user access by using" Authorize" attribute on role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

I work on asp.net MVC 3

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,SubAdmin")]
public ActionResult AdminProfile()
{
    return View();
}
```

How do i do to asp.net MVC understand the code above and filter correctly follow Role ? 
Roles did not get from database.

Answer (score 2):

You have to either use the default roles provider provided by asp.net or implement your own roles provider if you want to use your own schema. You can read more there about implementing your own roles provider http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74(v=vs.100).aspx.

Another option could also be to implement your own authorization filter, it might be easier than implementing a complete roles provider.

Comment: Yep, good answer @ryudice. In my experience, implementing your own AuthorizeAttribute is easier. It's also easy to control on larger apps where you need to restrict only certain controller actions by certain roles.